# Display Image from Embedded Resource in HTML in .NET App

Tags: c#, html, vb.net

I create a HTML report inside a .net application, into which I want to display an image, which is going to come from a DLL where it is stored as an embedded resource.

There are situations where I might have limited access to the file system. Even still, what is the best way to get the image out of the embedded resource (I can do this programmatically into a bitmap object) and display it in the html report for the user, preferably without using the file system. The HTML is created by the app.

Some more info:

The report is created by traversing a tree of objects in code, each of which return a piece of html:

```
Function GetReportLine() as String
    Return String.Format("<p>Account Created on {0}</p>", CreatedTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt"))
End Function
```

These are then compiled into a string, decorated with some CSS, and passed into a WebBrowser control embedded on a Form to display to the user.

I want to display an image from my embedded resource like this:

```
Return String.Format("<p><img src=MyEmbeddedResourceImage>Account Created on {0}</p>", CreatedTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this; it streams the image as a resource, not as a physical file:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2005/07/18/419842.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I understand what I am meant to do here. I have updated my initial question with some more details. Please help me understand if I can still use the info at that lionk to solve my problem.

Comment: Do this:  Return String.Format("<p><img src='{1}'>Account Created on {0}</p>", CreatedTime.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm tt"), Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(..)) - put in the parameters of the type and the full path of the image in the DLL, as specified in that blog post.